# How do I know the actual letter size of a TrueType font?

Tags: fonts, height, font-size, truetype

Which TrueType font table stores information about the actual character layout. That is, the size in pixels or points with which the symbol is displayed on the monitor.

For reference: I am working with font tables using the fontTools library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glyphs' heights are not specified anywhere (at least, not for a horizontal layout). Probably, what you're looking for is [sxHeight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/os2#sxheight) from the 'OS/2' table (the distance between the baseline and the approximate height of non-ascending lowercase letters). There's also [sxCapHeight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/os2#scapheight) field (for uppercase letters). Though, those fields were defined in the second version of the OS/2 table.

To find out the glyph's height, you can simply subtract its lowest point from the highest one (i.e. glyph height = yMax - yMin). yMax and yMin are stored in [Glyph Header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/glyf) in the 'glyf' table (for TrueType outlines).

If you need glyphs' widths, '[hmtx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/hmtx)' table contains an advance width for every glyph in a font, as well as left-side bearing (right-side bearing is not stored, when needed it has to be computed from left-side-bearing + maxX - minX). '[hhea](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/hhea)' table contains a maximum advance width value (advanceWidthMax).

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you tell us what units of measurement ssheight uses from the OS/2 table, yMax and yMin from the glyf table

Comment: And one more question. I need to fit a word from characters in any font into a string of a given size, how would you personally do this?

Comment: @Paitor Units are font units (smallest unit in the em square, which is unitsPerEm). I didn't quite understand your second question, sorry.

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference between Units and Funits  (I read about this unit here learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/ttch01). I do not know if you can help me with my question, but I will try to rephrase it. Here you are given a string, let's say 100 px, and you are given a text that needs to be printed in a certain font so that this text fits right into the string (for example, you need to write "hello world" in Calibri font). How would you do this, what data would you use?

Comment: @Paitor Size isn't measured in just "units", you can't just use some kind of abstract unit, but there's a concrete unit called "font unit" (or FUnit), which is used for measuring OpenType fonts.

Comment: @Paitor So, if I got you right, you want to calculate text width with a given font and size. You can try doing it by yourself, but you'll have a pretty imprecise result because you need to consider such things as kerning, hinting, etc. So, basically, you'll have to write your own mini-rasterizer. And the text's width will also be different when using different rasterizers. Rasterizers usually have an API for calculating text's width (for example, java.awt has FontMetrics.stringWidth).

Comment: To be honest, I didn't understand much. So this data from the tables won't help me in any way? Also, you didn't answer the question about units

Comment: @Paitor In short, it will take a lot of calculations and font processing, and the result won't be perfect. You need to use a rasterizer's API to calculate the text's width. About units: I answered you 3 comments before. I'll try to explain it once more. FUnit IS a unit used in measuring glyphs (i.e. font unit). Sorry if my explanation is not clear.

Comment: OK, thanks for everything again)). I'll go read about these " rasterizer's APIs"

Comment: @Paitor I see you asked a question about Pillow. I don't know anything about this library or Python, but there's a function for calculating string width. It's what I meant by "rasterizer's API". Take a look at it: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.textsize

Comment: It seems that this method returns the size of the already created text, but I need to do the opposite, knowing the size of the string to choose the size of the text for it

Comment: @Paitor You need to call this function a few times with different font sizes and choose the maximum one that fits.

Comment: I found this text (I divided it into several comments), do you think this way you can adjust the font characters to the size of the line?
Converting Units to pixels
Values in the em square are converted to values in the pixel coordinate system bymultiplying them by a scale. This scale is: point Size * resolution / ( 72 points per inch * units_per_em ). Where point Size is the size at which the glyph is to be displayed, and resolution is the resolution of the output device. The 72 in the denominator reflects the number of points per inch.

Comment: For example, assume that a glyph feature is 550 Units in length on a 72 dpi screen at 18 point. There are 2048 units per em. The following calculation reveals that the feature is 4.83 pixels long. 550 * 18 * 72 / ( 72 * 2048 ) = 4.83